# Cloud batch submission API?

Tags: cloud, virtualization, saas, paas, iaas

This is a question about APIs, not vendors. Please keep your answers vendor-neutral.

The question is language-agnostic but I don't mind an answer which is language-specific.

Suppose I am going to write a program which I want to compile and then submit for execution in the cloud.

What API can I call which enables me to just pass in the compiled program (such as an executable or jar file or DLL) along with some parameters (e.g. how many CPUs and memory to allocate) and receive back the output of the program?

I am looking for an API that takes the compiled program as a parameter. Specifically I do not want to use the common cloud APIs which require first provisioning and spinning up a server, deploying the software, retrieving results, and tearing down the server all in separate steps.